# Python module not installing completely

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging

I have created a python module having the following hierarchy

Git Repository : [Zeus | Machine Learning Library](https://github.com/shibli2700/shibli2700.github.io/)

[image]

But whenever I run the command

```
python setup.py install
```

It successfully installs the module but when I try to import anything from the submodules it gives an error eg.

when I run this in my python terminal

```
import zeus
```

It works totally fine, but when I run this

```
from zeus.tree import classifiers
```

it gives me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from zeus.tree import classifiers
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zeus.tree'
```

I guess its the problem with my **init**.py but don't know what exactly it is.

Comment: You did not add your submodules to `setup.py`.

Comment: can u please tell me how to add them?

Comment: can you share your `setup.py` file too ?

Comment: u can find the setup.py file in the GitHub repository I have shared the Link of my repo above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    from distutils.core import setup

    setup(
        name = "zeus",
        version = "0.1",
        author = "yourname",
        author_email = "youraddress@xyz.com",
        description = ("A simple and easy to use Machine Learning Library."),
        license = "GPL-2,0",
        packages=['zeus', 'zeus.tree', 'zeus.linear_regressors'],
        install_requires=['numpy'],
        zip_safe=False
    )
```

Your packaging didn't include the sub modules which is causing the import error. The changed line is:

```
    packages=['zeus', 'zeus.tree', 'zeus.linear_regressors']
```

Instead you only had:

```
    packages=['zeus']
```